# Identify aero handlebars that are easy to work with?

Tags: handlebars, cable-routing

Can anyone share examples of aero handlebars that are easy to work on?  Preferably with some type of external routing.

ENVE SES AR handlebars seem to be close to this concept.
[image]

I'm on the Pro Vibe Aero handlebar now and it's a pain to route cabling through it.

Comment: Can’t you just route the cables externally without using the holes? A little tape will hold them in place before you wrap the bar tape on.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles. Our Q&A site is a little different than a typical forum, and generally product recommendation or "shopping" questions are considered off topic. An on-topic alternative to this question would be something like "How do you make it easier re-cable handlebars with internal routing." You can edit this question and flag it to be reopened and one of the moderators will review it. In the meantime, you can take the [tour] to see how this and other StackExchange sites work.